# javascript is synchronous programming language, isn't it?

Tags: javascript

I try to rotate an image and then set it's transition:"transform 2s". Here is my code:

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".top-slide-container ul li");
nodeList[0].style.transition = "transform 0s";
nodeList[0].style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)";
nodeList[0].style.transition = "transform 2s";
```

When i run this code. The result isn't like what i think. The image rotate in 2s. Can anyone explain why it didn't do this in 0s? javascript is synchronous programming language, isn't it?

Comment: `2s` is what you have specified in the code!

Comment: hint - `"transform 2s";` last line

Comment: what i think is : nodeList[0].style.transition = "transform 0s"; finish -> nodeList[0].style.transform = "rotateY(90deg)"; finish -> nodeList[0].style.transition = "transform 2s";

Comment: Your issue here is with CSS not JS

Comment: An image that rotated in 0s would look exactly the same, wouldn't it? I'm not sure how you would tell is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Javascript runs synchronously. But browser rendering is a different story. However browser rendering (and processing styles which is really a seperate process) is usually blocked while Javascript is executing. Hence the style setting applied in the second line of your code is overwritten by the fourth line before the browser attempts to carry out the changes.

Comment: Thanks you! Can i use setTimeOut or fire an event to make transform: 2s when the rotate finish to fix that?

Comment: @khoibn Yes - I use `setTimeout` in order to allow the browser to render changes, whenever I come across an issue like this.

Comment: Yes, but if you trigger an event, then the event processing will begin before the execution thread returns to the rendering engine. You might want to have a look at requestanimationframe() which was specifically added to address this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok man, I see you're a bit confused about execution logic, so I can try to explain you a little bit about what is going on under the hood when you run your code.

1.
    nodeList[0].style.transition = "transform 0s";

This is just going to set the transition css rule for the specified element in your app.

2. Then you add a csss transform which is fine as well
3. nodeList[0].style.transition = "transform 2s";

well, this is really called after the previous 2 lines of code but, because JavaScript "read" a line of code in a really little fraction of second (~1ms), this is going to overwrite almost immediately your first assertion.

JavaScript execute one line after another in the sequence you wrote the code in your texteditor, however it is not going to wait until the DOM has been updated with the code. It just run, dude!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is synchronous but its not "blocking / locking" the UI. The browser will render (asynchronous).

I assume you want to change the property after the animation is finished?

Here is some library for css animations. In there docs they described how  "You can also detect when an animation ends:"

```js
function doSomething(){
  alert('Animation End');
}

$('#yourElement').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', doSomething);
```

open source libs:
https://github.com/daneden/animate.css